# Force Azure Function using Service Bus Queues to only process one mesage at a time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have followed the instructions in the link [here](https://laurakokkarinen.com/forcing-an-azure-function-to-process-queue-storage-messages-one-at-a-time/) to try to get an Azure function to process messages in a queue 1 by 1

I am using Azure Service Bus Queues

I deliberately added a delay into the function to slow it down, but I can see that a queue of 250 messages is processed very quickly, despite me adding a delay of a second into the function

Has anyone had issues with trying to do this?

I have this in my host.json

```
 "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0,
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:30",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "maxDequeueCount": 3
    }
```

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you're referring to is about Azure Storage Queues. For Azure Service Bus, there are several configuration settings you should check, such as `maxConcurrentCalls` (16 by default) and `maxConcurrentSessions` if you're using sessions. More information in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings).

Comment: Ok so maybe I just need to set those both to 1 not sure if the rest are related and I don’t see the service bus version of maxDequeueCount

Comment: There's no max dequeue count on ASB. ASB works differently. See `MaxDeliveryCount` in ASB documentation.